# Tag concatenation for displaying dictionaries dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I Have a dictionary (dict_) returned from my view. inside the template i want to access specific keys. How can i do that?

```
{% for a in applications %}
{{ dict_.a.id}}
{% endfor %}
```

from view:

```
context = {
    'applications': applications,
    'dict_': count_dict
}

return render(request, 'applications/map.html', context)
```

Do i need to concat it?
E.g.

`{{ dict_ }} + {{ a.id }}`

Update. Here is my view:

```
def MapView(request):
    applications = Application.objects.values(
        'name', 'id', 'icon_name').filter(organization_id=1).order_by('name')

    context = {
        'applications': applications,
        'devices_count': [(a, devices.filter(id=a['id']).count()) for a in applications]
    }

    return render(request, 'applications/map.html', context)
```

Comment: While you can make  template tag, it is *not* advisable to do that. Django's templates deliberately do not allow indexing, because business logic should be written in the *view*, not in the *template*.

Comment: The way it is returned from the view is written on the view. The way i want to access the dictionary, isn't part of the template? I return multiple dictionaries

Comment: you can do the mapping already *in* the view.

Comment: You mean serializing into json data and return the whole json? I would appriciate if you could share a link on this

Comment: no, you simply channel every `application` already through the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's templates are *deliberately* restricted to make it inconvenient to perform dictionary lookups like that, or to make function calls (with parameters). The reason is that business logic is better written in the *view*, not in the template.

You can for example make the mapping in the view, like:

```
context = {
    'app_counts': [(a, count_dict[a.id]) for a in applications]
}

return render(request, 'applications/map.html', context)
```

then you can render this with:

```
{% for app, count in app_counts %}
    {{ app }}: {{ count }}
{% endfor %}
```